# Merging two tensors based on time series

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series, dataset, tensor

I have two tensors:

```
A -> (128,19,3,99,99) #(batch, date, data, data, data)
B -> (128,9,223)  #(batch, date, data)
```

After encoding I will have something like that:

```
A2 -> (128,19,10) # (batch, date, encoded data with CNN_1)
B2 -> (128,9,10) # (batch, date, encoded data with CNN_2)
C -> (128,28,10) # merge of A2 and B2
```

I have the records of time-series of each tensor `(A,B)`,
I want to be able to merge them on `date` axis to a single tensor.

Here is an example of the time series of tensor A:
`['2021-12-13', '2021-12-28', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-20', '2022-01-26', '2022-02-06', '2022-02-14', '2022-02-22', '2022-03-02', '2022-03-17', '2022-03-21', '2022-03-27', '2022-03-30', ...]`
Tensor B has different dates that do not necessarily fall on the exact dates of tensor A.

So in the end, the axis of the `date` in tensor `C` will be something like this:
`A2,A2,B2,A2,B2,A2,B2,B2` depends on the original order of dates.

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer : )

```
import torch

# Merged Tensors
A0_RGB = torch.rand((128,19,3))
A1_Hyper = torch.rand((128,9,3))


# Merge and find the order
A2_concat = torch.concat((A0_RGB,A1_Hyper), dim=1)
A3_sorted_v, A3_sorted_i = A2_concat[0,:,0].sort()

# Restore original order
A5_test_selection = A2_concat[:,A3_sorted_i,:]
```

Just the concept...

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked.